# Showing a website properly in a social media post?

Tags: html, facebook

If you post a status update or a comment with a link of a website on facebook, the link shows a picture and a few line about the website. Where do you put this information, this picture and the words about the site, in your html?  In the ?  What tags?  Where do i put the link to the picture shown in the link on social media?

Comment: Could be the [`<meta>` tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp).

Comment: @Zera probably. But which. I found these on fb.  <meta property="og: xxxxx" content="xxxxx"/>

Comment: [Complete list of HTML meta tags](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/1978404).

Comment: @Zera, thx.Think this might be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook (and most other social networks) use ["Open Graph" meta tags](https://ogp.me/) if they're available.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```